# Can not uninstall globally installed npm package

Tags: node.js, npm

Running `npm uninstall -g angular2@2.0.0-beta.17`

does not remove the folder under:

```
C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular2
```

the CMD waits for 1 second then a new  line is created and nothing really happened.

How can I remove the globally installed package then the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you specify the wrong name or version. Try just: `npm uninstall -g angular2`